# Native module in react native, cannot call "this" in java class

Tags: java, android, react-native

help meeee....!
In my react native project, and created a native module 'BeaconModule' to use some function that react native does not support. in android project, it works fine. but when i coppy function AIBeaconManager.init() to reactnative project, it got some error bellow.

- this is my code

```
public class BeaconModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements AIBeaconListener{
  private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

  BeaconModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
    super(context);
    reactContext = context;

    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put(AIBeaconManagerInitOption.Keys.AutoServiceRegistrationEnabled, Boolean.valueOf(true));
            put(AIBeaconManagerInitOption.Keys.PushNotificationEnabled, Boolean.valueOf(true));
        }};
    AIBeaconManager aiBeaconManager = AIBeaconManager.init(this, "1062", "09CYvck2rZVNlpQI", options);
  }
```

- error:

```
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/Users/admin/Documents/Working/GPass/GPass/android/app/src/main/java/com/gpass/BeaconModule.java:57: error: incompatible types: BeaconModule cannot be converted to Context
    AIBeaconManager aiBeaconManager = AIBeaconManager.init(this, "1062", "09CYvck2rZVNlpQI", options); 
                                                           ^
Note: /Users/admin/Documents/Working/GPass/GPass/android/app/src/debug/java/com/gpass/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I think it because difference between 'Context' and 'ReactApplicationContext'

Comment: You have an extra open bracket before your `this`.